# nativescript-ng2-carousel error after installing when run tns build android

Tags: java, android, angular, nativescript

I am making a nativescript app and want to add a carousel by using nativescript-ng2-carousel but after I did npm i nativescript-ng2-carousel I get an error saying

Warning: there already is an extend called com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.
Warning: there already is an extend called com.tns.FragmentClass.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: File already exists. This may lead to undesired behavior.
Please change the name of one of the extended classes.
File:D:\Documents\coursera_examples\nativescript\VilcabambaHotel\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\tns\gen\java\lang\Object_button_19_32_ClickListenerImpl.java Class:
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:81)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:47)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:runSbg'.

  > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

I have tried updating my typescript, I have deleted node_modules and reinstalled, I have removed and added platforms and still get the same error

Comment: This error doesn't seem to be related to the plugin. Does it go away when remove the plugin?

Comment: yes if I remove the plugin it goes away

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the problem with the plugin. But why don't you try `nativescript-pager` or `nativescript-carousel`?